# Putting a timer on a File in Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

So I'm in the process of creating a social media app, and I'm storing the post information on Mongo and the actual file on Firebase storage. So whenever a user uploads a file it directly goes to Firebase even if they don't click "Submit". So as not to waste storage I want some way that these files get deleted after a certain period of time. I have considered running a Firebase Cloud Functions every 5 minutes in order to scan and delete any images with perhaps a certain tag. Perhaps there is a method of using a custom meta-tag in the file itself. So far it seems that nothing of the sort exists.

### Edit: Found the Answer, its below but here it is also

I figured it out, and its pretty complicated. So a Cloud Function would be triggered upon ever Upload Request and it would create a Firestone document with a In-use parameter set to false by default. Then assuming you have your own rest API on every post you would search firestore for a document that contains the same image URL and set the in use to true. Of course there would be a cloud function that would be triggered about 5 minutes after a file gets uploaded.

Comment: Have a look at scheduled Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage Node.js Admin SDK.

Comment: Doug's blog post here describes a very similar use-case, but then for documents in the Firestore database: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks that article is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, and its pretty complicated. So a Cloud Function would be triggered upon ever Upload Request and it would create a Firestone document with a `In-use` parameter set to false by default. Then assuming you have your own rest API on every post you would search firestore for a document that contains the same image URL and set the in use to true. Of course there would be a cloud function that would be triggered about 5 minutes after a file gets uploaded.